# excel show custom vlookup tooltip/popup/comment on over cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you could help, don't know if its possible.
I'm using Excel to create a layout with some ID's in that layout.

Since it's a layout, I can't just show all information needed as it's too much, so, I would like with a click in that cell or when mouse hover it shows a tooltip/comment with a custom vlookup that search that ID in another sheet. When the user click in a empty cell or takes mouse point to an empty cell the tooltip/comment disappear.

Already make some searches but couldn't find anything. Any suggestions in how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051576/create-tooltip-using-mousemove-on-activex-checkbox

Comment: I guess I made with but in another way. Thanks.